# Checkin and publish all files inside a folder using csom

Tags: 2013, 2010, csom, check-in

I want to checkin and publish all the files inside a folder and its sub-folders

Below is my code

```
private void checkinFile(ClientContext ctx, string foldername) {
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web, a => a.Lists);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(foldername);
            var files = list.GetItems(
                new CamlQuery()
                {
                    ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query> 
            <Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser' /></IsNotNull></Where> 
            </Query></View>"
                });
            ctx.Load(files);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                file.File.CheckIn("Add", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

        }
```

Usage
**`package.checkinFile(ctx, "Style Library");`**

This is not publishing/check-in the files the style library sub folders

Answer (score 1):

Found out the issue

I missed to add the `ctx.executequery`

So the below code works fine

```
private void checkinFile(ClientContext ctx, string foldername) {
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web, a => a.Lists);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(foldername);
            var files = list.GetItems(
                new CamlQuery()
                {
                    ViewXml = @"<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><Query> 
            <Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='CheckoutUser' /></IsNotNull></Where> 
            </Query></View>"
                });
            ctx.Load(files);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                file.File.CheckIn("Add", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------");
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
```

I thought of deleting the question since it hasn't got answers from others, but then I couldnt find this snippet in SO and I thought this might help someone in future

Comment: Please accept your solution as answer. so that it will helpful for other  users

Comment: sure Tarun will do
looks like I can accept my answer only after 2 days :)